# Android dynamic image file name

Tags: java, android

I have the following code that will save the image named "pic.jpg" into the external storage folder.

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mFile = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "pic.jpg");

    }
```

How can I go about creating a dynamic image name?
For example, pic.jpg already exist. Then, the next image name will be pic01.jpg.

Answer (score 1):

```
mFile = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "pic.jpg");
int counter = 1;
while (mFile.exists()) {
   mFile = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "pic" + String.format("%02d", counter) + ".jpg");
   counter++;
}
```

Comment: While this will solve the problem, imo this isn't the best solution. worst case is o(n), it's better to save the count in a shared preference and increment it everytime a new file is made.